# MonoDevelop not support display Thai font

Tags: internationalization, xamarin.ios, gtk, monodevelop, thai

I'm now learning iPhone development with Monotouch and use Mono Develop for IDE. Everything works fine and I'm going to buy a license for MonoTouch. However, the IDE can not display Thai text correctly.
It just display [] that is difficult for me to type message in Thai. Although this text display correct in runtime (iPhone Simulator).
I think this problem occurs in MonoDevelop.

Please could you help me to solve this problem.
PS. I tried everything that I can do.  For example, change file format to UTF 8 , 16 and copy text from other programs that display Thai text correctly.

I'm looking forward to hearing from you
Theeranit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the library that MonoDevelop uses for font rendering on Mac, called Pango, has problems with font fallbacks. That means that if the primary font doen't contain the character you want, it can't fall back to another font for that character.

You can work around this by setting a custom font in MonoDevelop preferences. Set it to a font that contains Thai characters.